# Transfer object to a predetermined distance

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I have an object at coordinates `(0, 0, 0)` and I want to translate this object in any direction a predetermined distance, for example `5`.

How do I to find the final coordinates? (**not iteratively checking**)

Comment: what is your move function

Comment: More information is required because `5` essentially represents the radius   of a sphere positioned at `(0, 0, 0)`.  The _"final coordinates"_ is _any_ point on the surface on that sphere of which **there are infinite**.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is how do you generate a point that is 5 away from the origin (0,0,0). In general, you can use the [parametric equations of a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Equations_in) to generate these points by first picking two random numbers in the range [0, 2pi] and [0, pi] respectively, then your point is

```
x = r * cos(theta) * sin(phi)
y = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
z = r * cos(phi)
```

Where theta is the first random number, phi is the second and r is your distance from the origin.

In Unity, it is even easier as you can use `Random.onUnitSphere` to give you a point exactly 1 away from the origin. Then just multiply by 5, e.g.:

```
finalPosition = Random.onUnitSphere * r
```

Again, where r in your example would be 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve exactly the same as T.Kiley said just picking a totally random vector, it will have a random direction and random magnitude. You can then normalize that vector and multiply it by 5 (or the desired magnitude).